# how can i remove the parameter from index.php htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have problem with my htaccess code the problem is i dont know how can i display the code for index.php , 
 the code that i'm using is

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^Page/([^/]*)$ /Page.php?v=$1 [L]
```

and my output link is  `www.expample.com/Page/1`

the code above sis working for every thing except the index page

what i need to do now is

index.php instead of Page.php

i tried this way

```
       RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ /index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

but also it's not working

the output that i need now is to convert the link from

`www.example.com/index.php?v=1`  to `www.example.com/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For second `index.php` rule you need to use `RewriteCond` to avoid rewriting for files or directories:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Page/([^/]*)$ Page.php?v=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# if request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

RewriteRule ^1/?$ index.php?v=1 [QSA,L]

I think you should not use /index.php try index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to rewrite to your index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

That should handle any location of /index.php.